# Resize Corner takes a lot of space in GNOME

Tags: 20.04, gnome

The resize corner takes a lot of space. At least half an inch of space in all four sides of any window of a program. How should I scale it down.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Is it theme dependent?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi the problem was due to a bad scripted theme. It's no longer a problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused due to a bad scripted theme.